# Galois group of $GF(p^n): \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I’m struggling to understand one part of this proof. I understand that the size of $GF(p^n)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $n$ and that the Frobenius automorphism $\Phi$ is an element of the Galois group. I fail to understand why the order of $\Phi$ is $n$.

The order of $\Phi$ divides $n$ by Cauchy’s theorem. The order of $\Phi$ is the smallest $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\Phi ^m = id $ i.e. the smallest $m$ such that $\Phi ^m (x) = id(x)  \; \; \forall x \in GF(p^n)$ or equivalently $(x^p)^m = x^{pm}=x$.

We know that $x^{p^n}=x \;\; \forall x \in GF(p^n)$ but I don’t know how to apply this to show m=n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\text{Fr}:\mathbf{F}_{p^n}\to \mathbf{F}_{p^n},x\mapsto x^p$ be the Frobenius automorphism.

For every $d<n$, $\text{Fr}^d$ is not the identity on $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$, since $X^{p^d}-X$ has at most $p^d$ roots.

---

*Edit*. I will elaborate a bit. If $\text{Fr}^d$ were the identity for $d<n$, then all $x\in \mathbf{F}_{p^n}$ would satisfy $x^{p^d}=x$. Contradiction, since $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$ contains $p^n$ elements and $X^{p^d}-X$ has at most $p^d$ roots. (This is a result from basic ring theory: a polynomial of degree $m$ over an integral domain as at most $m$ roots.)

Comment: And the identity has $p^n$ root?

Comment: How can you say that polynomial has at most $p^d$ roots. Is that not just to do with complex analysis?

Comment: $Fr ^d (x) = ({x^p})^d = x^pd$ no?? So why pick $x^{p^d} - x$ as polynomial?

Comment: No, $\text{Fr}^d(x)=\underbrace{\text{Fr}\circ \text{Fr} \circ \ldots \circ \text{Fr}}_{d\text{ times}}(x)=\underbrace{\left(\left((x^p)^p\right)^{\cdots}\right)^p}_{d\text{ times}}=x^{p^d}$.

Comment: Thank you. I think that’s the big mistake I made. If I have known that then I would not have had to ask question.

Comment: Do you consider the polynomial $X^{p^d} - X$ to be a polynomial of Z_p or GP(p^n)?

Comment: @Anteater23 In $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}[X]$. Glad I could be of help :)